# Which Azure role should I use?

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-web-roles

I'm planning an application that has a mobile app as a front end (and perhaps a web front end also that performs a different purpose). Something like Runkeeper, or Runtastic, if you're familiar with those apps. The mobile device is the primary method of user interaction, and the web site has stats and dashboards that the users can view afterwards.

I would like the main application to reside in Windows Azure. I'm confused about how to architect the application though - should the business logic reside in a web role, or a worker role? If the main user interface is a mobile app, does it connect to the worker role to persist or retrieve data, or to a web role, or neither? I understand a typical scenario where a web role provides a user interface which can persist data directly to storage or pass data to queues or tables to be picked up by worker roles, but the presence of the mobile app throws me off.

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For hosting a server component for mobile apps to connect to, I think the simplest thing that would work would be a web role hosting an ASP.NET web application.  Web applications can be used for services as well as web front end (HTML) web sites.

[ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) and [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) make setting up web services really easy, and it's easy to work with non-HTML data formats, such as JSON or XML.  Your mobile app could communicate with the web app using a REST JSON API, or you could use XML/SOAP if you wanted to, or whatever format you want.  REST APIs with JSON as the transfer format is probably the most popular at the moment.  One way to think about a web app is that it's just a way to send and recieve data from clients.  If the client is a web browser, you can serve up your content as HTML pages, or if your client is a mobile app, you can serve up your data as JSON and let the client display it however it needs to.  Basically, your web app can be both your web site (HTML), and your "API" for non-web-browser clients.

You can think of worker roles sort of like Windows Services.  They are primarily used for doing back-end processing, and things like that.  A worker role might provide some capability to host a public facing API, but you would have to manage connections, message pipelines, recycling, and all that yourself; whereas, a web role would have a web server (IIS) provided for you to manage connections, etc.  If you are going to introduce things like message queues, it would make sense to have the public facing API be a web role, and the message processing component a worker role.  The web app could receive the message from the client via a REST JSON API, and then pass the message off to a queue, where the worker role picks it up.  Introducing queues and worker roles makes sense if you have heavy-duty server-side business logic that can be processed in the background without impacting the client.

Comment: Good answer, but part of it is not quite true. A Worker Role is a Windows Server VM, just like a Web Role, only that IIS is not enabled. A Worker Role should *not* be thought of as a Windows Service: It's a VM. Anything you can run in a Web Role, you can run in a Worker Role. And... not reading ahead, I see that @smarx already pointed this out. So ignore me.

Comment: Yeah, I know what I said is not technically 100% accurate, but I was just trying to make an analogy to help understand when you would use a worker role vs. a web role.  Web == IIS, Worker == No IIS.

Answer (score 4):

Andy's answer is great, but let me add a different flavor. The *only* difference between a web role and a worker role is that the web role automatically has IIS turned on and configured. A good rule of thumb is that if you want IIS, use a web role. If you don't want IIS, use a worker role.

Comment: Thanks Smarx, that's helpful. Andy pointed out that IIS will handle certain things like connections, message pipelines, recycling, etc. My understanding of a worker role, however, is that it is also designed to run on a schedule, like the one that comes in its run and onstart methods (i.e. that inscrutable while(true) block - I'm still trying to figure out what is being evaluated as true there). Can a worker role sit passively and wait for a request from a client, or is that part of what IIS provides?

Comment: The worker role can do anything. Windows Azure just loads up your DLL and calls `OnStart` and then `Run`. You can do whatever you want in there, as long as you don't return from the call to `Run`. (If you do, Windows Azure will think your process crashed and will restart it.) So you can open a socket in `Run` or launch a web server (e.g. Apache) or whatever you want. In fact, Java web apps are almost always run in worker roles, not web roles. (We should all call it the "*IIS* role," not "web role.")

Comment: Thanks smarx. You overestimate me if you think I can go in there and start slinging java in an apache server, but I get your point ;-).